# What are the OS X Mavericks hardware system requirements?

Tags: imac, hardware, macos, system-requirements

I have a fairly old (I am not sure when it was bought) iMac 5,1 running OS X 10.6.8, but I just saw the free upgrade to Mavericks. It looks tempting, but I'd rather first know if my computer can handle this OS before I try to install it.

Processor: 2.16 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
Memory: 4 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM

(I guess that covers the most relevant hardware, if something else is important I'll add it.)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because the site works better if answers are posted as such. Once you find out how they got Mavericks on a white Macbook can you please add this as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, of course, but AFAIK I can't call the shop today because they are closed, and I wanted to explain why I unaccepted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1758?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), the iMac5,1 was released in 2006, and is thus not on the [list of models that are supported by Mavericks](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/). Whether Mavericks can be hacked to run on your machine is a different question.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly thought I saw another computer as old as mine running Mavericks, so I thought I could get Mavericks to run because this computer has a RAM upgrade, so I unaccepted your answer (and now accepted it again).

Answer (score 6):

System requirements can be found at [Apple - Upgrade your Mac to OS X Mavericks](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/). Click the **View compatible Mac models** link under the **Check your Mac hardware** step to view the supported models.  Currently:

> **Mac models compatible with OS X Mavericks**
>
> - iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)
> - MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
> - MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)
> - MacBook Air (Late 2008 or newer)
> - Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)
> - Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
> - Xserve (Early 2009)

From the Apple menu select "About This Mac" and then click the "More Info…" button to determine exactly what model you have.

According to the information at [How to identify iMac models](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1758), the iMac5,1 is the Late 2006 model, which is **not** compatible with OS X Mavericks.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not sure when it was bought exactly. It could have been mid 2007, but it could have been earlier as well.

Comment: Have you tried clicking the Apple menu in the menu bar and selecting "About This Mac"? There may be a "more info" section that tells the specific model of the Mac.

Comment: From the Apple menu select "About This Mac" and then click the "More Info…" button to determine exactly what model you have.

Comment: iMac5,1 (it has extra RAM though). How do I turn that model name into a year?

Comment: @11684: Use the free [MacTracker](http://mactracker.ca/). It will identify the model of the machine it's running on. The model year has not much to do with when you bought it.

Comment: On a side note, MacTracker isn't bugfree. Before buying extra RAM, they looked up this Mac in the shop on MacTracker, which said it would only detect 3 GB of RAM. Instead it detected all four gigabytes. @KubaOber

Answer (score 1):

You have the same iMac as me, which is the last white plastic iMac model before transitioning to the more rational aluminum body.  That's a mid-2006 for future, and unless someone knows of a script to trick the OS into thinking it's an older model, 10.6.8 is as far as we can go.

Bummer, right?

Comment: I believe Lion is compatible as well.

Answer (score -2):

I think maverick should run inspite of apple official required models. Y also have a i mac mid 2006 with snow leopard.

Comment: Should this be an edit to an existing answer or a comment there? If not, let's flush it out with some details and reasoning why you believe Mavericks will run on hardware where it's not supported.